# Jinja2 - Given 2 templates (as strings) how to render one that extends the other?

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I'm making a simple script that works on Jinja2 templates. Right now it's just reading files in from disk manually, i.e. no Jinja Loaders. I have 2 strings (`A` and `B`), representing 2 templates. I want to make one template (`B`) inherit from the other (`A`), i.e. I have `{% block body %}{% endblock %}` in `A`, and I want to make the body block be the contents of B. How can I get the rendered output of this?

Normally I'd use `{% extends 'filename' %}` in `B` and it'd use the right one, however I don't have the filename (per se) for A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet probably to use a different [template loader](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#loaders).  Take a look at [DictLoader](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.DictLoader) and [FunctionLoader](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.FunctionLoader), or try your hand a writing your own template loader.